# SQL query to separate pipe delimited with empty values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called as contents:

```
create table contents(file_name varchar2(4000), file_content clob);
```

Here is the table:

```
file_name                                  file_content
deID.RESUL_12433287659.txt_234323456.txt   |678976|TEST|TBDKK|7865679809
deID.RESUL_34534563649.txt_345353567.txt   1|678977||TB5KK|7866709
deID.RESUL_44235345636.txt_537967875.txt   |678978|TE2T|TB4KK|78669809
deID.RESUL_35234663456.txt_423452545.txt   4|678979|TE3T|T3DKK|785679809
```

I need to create another table called as data_contents using contents with the following structure:

```
file_name                                  id  number   name  address  phone
deID.RESUL_12433287659.txt_234323456.txt       678976   TEST  TBDKK    7865679809
deID.RESUL_34534563649.txt_345353567.txt    1  678977         TB5KK    7866709
deID.RESUL_44235345636.txt_537967875.txt       678978   TE2T  TB4KK    78669809
deID.RESUL_35234663456.txt_423452545.txt    4  678979   TE3T  T3DKK    785679809
```

I tried with this query:

```
with DTE as
(
    select file_name, 
           to_char(file_content) as file_content -- preconvert the clob to a varchar
    from MyTable
)
, CTE as
(
    select file_name, 
           case 
             when substr(file_content,1,1) ='|' -- If the string starts with the delimiter
               then ' '||file_content -- then add a space at the start
             else file_content 
           end as file_content
    from DTE
)

    select file_name,
           regexp_substr (file_content, '[^|]+',1, 1 ) as id,
           regexp_substr (file_content, '[^|]+',1, 2 ) as thenumber, 
           regexp_substr (file_content, '[^|]+',1, 3 ) as thename,
           regexp_substr (file_content, '[^|]+',1, 4 ) as theaddress,
           regexp_substr (file_content, '[^|]+',1, 5) as phone
    from CTE
```

If there is any field which is blank, for ex. the second row, where name does not exist, then it is being ignored by my query and because of that all the column values shift one cell.

Is there anyway to put NULL value if there are no values in any column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like so:

```
with DTE as
(
  SELECT 'deID.RESUL_12433287659.txt_234323456.txt' file_name, '|678976|TEST|TBDKK|7865679809' file_content FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'deID.RESUL_34534563649.txt_345353567.txt' file_name, '1|678977||TB5KK|7866709' file_content FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'deID.RESUL_44235345636.txt_537967875.txt' file_name, '|678978|TE2T|TB4KK|78669809' file_content FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'deID.RESUL_35234663456.txt_423452545.txt' file_name, '4|678979|TE3T|T3DKK|785679809' file_content FROM dual
)
SELECT file_name,
       file_content,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_content, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) ID,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_content, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1) thenumber,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_content, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 3, NULL, 1) thename,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_content, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 4, NULL, 1) theaddress,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(file_content, '(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 5, NULL, 1) phone
FROM   dte;

FILE_NAME                                FILE_CONTENT                  ID THENUMBER THENAME THEADDRESS PHONE
---------------------------------------- ----------------------------- -- --------- ------- ---------- ------------
deID.RESUL_12433287659.txt_234323456.txt |678976|TEST|TBDKK|7865679809    678976    TEST    TBDKK      7865679809
deID.RESUL_34534563649.txt_345353567.txt 1|678977||TB5KK|7866709       1  678977            TB5KK      7866709
deID.RESUL_44235345636.txt_537967875.txt |678978|TE2T|TB4KK|78669809      678978    TE2T    TB4KK      78669809
deID.RESUL_35234663456.txt_423452545.txt 4|678979|TE3T|T3DKK|785679809 4  678979    TE3T    T3DKK      785679809
```

(I've replaced your DTE with a subquery mimicking data in your table; you would use the same DTE as you already have.)

This works by matching 0 or more characters followed by either the `|` delimiter (which we have to escape, since it's a special character in regular expressions), or the end of the string.

Then we find the nth occurrence, depending on which column we're after.

Finally, we need the final option to restrict the value returned to the values in the first set of brackets (i.e. the text defined by `.*?`), otherwise you get the values with the `|` appended as well, instead of just the value.

Comment: The columns have | at the end for each value.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't have a `|` at the end of the last value, which is why you need to check for either a `|` or the end-of-line terminator. You don't really need to check for the end-of-line terminator for the first 4 columns, but you've indicated in comments elsewhere that you want the same regexp for each column.

Comment: Using the query above, I am getting the value - 678976| and not 678976. Another example is TEST| and not TEST.

Comment: yeah, sorry - I thought I'd tested that the `null, 1` extra parameters weren't needed, but looking at it again, they are. Must have done something wrong in my initial test. I've already updated my answer, so you should take a look at the latest sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could just replace all '|' by ' |', so null values are taken into account, and then remove all extra space:

```
    with DTE as
(
    select file_name, 
           replace(to_char(file_content), '|', ' |') as file_content -- preconvert the clob to a varchar
    from MyTable
)
    select file_name,
           replace(regexp_substr (file_content, '[^|]+',1, 1 ), ' ', '') as id,
           replace(regexp_substr (file_content, '[^|]+',1, 2 ), ' ', '') as thenumber, 
           replace(regexp_substr (file_content, '[^|]+',1, 3 ), ' ', '') as thename,
           replace(regexp_substr (file_content, '[^|]+',1, 4 ), ' ', '') as theaddress,
           replace(regexp_substr (file_content, '[^|]+',1, 5), ' ', '') as phone
    from DTE;
```

Comment: What about the first empty pipe?

Comment: @dang It's handled by your CTE query, isn't it ?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. If I have multiple empty like |||, the above just replaces the first one and not the second one.

Comment: If I replace all |, then all my column values will have additional space. That's not a good way I believe.

Comment: @dang Oh then just add a space before each |. You do not even need your CTE query

Comment: @dang, you could just remove extra spaces and the end. Let me rewrite your query

Comment: what if the actual value has some space at the end? Aren't we removing the extra space?

Answer (score 0):

I  used a slightly different pattern that matches bot h the pipe and what is before the pipe (or after for the last value)

```
SELECT file_name,
   regexp_substr(file_content, '([A-Z0-9]*)(\|)',1,1,'',1) as id,
   regexp_substr(file_content, '([A-Z0-9]*)(\|)',1,2,'',1) as thenumber,
   regexp_substr(file_content, '([A-Z0-9]*)(\|)',1,3,'',1) as thename,
    regexp_substr(file_content, '([A-Z0-9]*)(\|)',1,4,'',1) as theaddress,
   regexp_substr(file_content, '(\|)([A-Z0-9]*)$',1,1,'',2) as phone
FROM CTE
```

Comment: I want to keep the pattern generic so it can be used with all the fields. Right now, for phone, you have used a different pattern.

Comment: @dang that's no problem. Note that my pattern is just an example based on your sample data.

Comment: Can you make the pattern same and still make it work?

Comment: @dang, oh you mean including the pipe? no but is it really necessary?

Comment: Check the last regex_substr, it has different pattern than the others. I would like to keep all same as I have a lot more columns available in my table.

Comment: @dang yes I know but does it matter if only the last one is different, no matter if you have 10 or 1000 columns there is always one and only one that is the last one.

Comment: Ok, let me try. Would this work if I have small case and not capital case?

Comment: @dang You can control that with the second last parameter, change ’’ to ’i’ to make the matchning case insensitive