# How can I split by a character without ignoring nulls?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to use [regexp_subst](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions116.htm) to split a delimited string. I'm running into an issue when delimited fields are null. The `regexp_substr` ignores the nulls and moves to the next occurrence  of the delimiter. Is there a way to do this with `regexp_substr`? If not, what alternative do you use?

```
--Expecting hello, gets hello
select regexp_substr('hello@@world', '[^@]+', 1, 1)
from dual;

--Expecting null, gets world
select regexp_substr('hello@@world', '[^@]+', 1, 2)
from dual;

--Expecting world, gets null
select regexp_substr('hello@@world', '[^@]+', 1, 3)
from dual;
```

EDIT: tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54807960/sql-query-to-separate-pipe-delimited-with-empty-values), but it works only with | which isn't an option

Comment: `+` means "one or more time" and `*` means "zero or more times". Also, to make the linked answer work, just change `\||$` to `@|$`?

Comment: Ah, I had tried changing \||$ to \@@$. I didn't realize the second | had a different meaning in the regular expression. @|$ works.

Comment: `\|` is just the `|` character itself (escaped with `\ ` to avoid it being interpretted as part of the language. `|` on its own is just `OR`. So, `\||$` would mean `'|' OR [end of line]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering based on Matbailie's input in above comment

```
select regexp_substr('hello@@world', '(.*?)(@|$)', 1, 1,NULL,1)
from dual
union all
--Expecting null, gets null
select regexp_substr('hello@@world', '(.*?)(@|$)', 1, 2,NULL,1)
from dual
union all
--Expecting world, gets world
select regexp_substr('hello@@world', '(.*?)(@|$)', 1, 3,NULL,1)
from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need regular expressions. It can be done with simple (and faster) string functions in a recursive sub-query:

```sql
WITH data (value) AS (
  SELECT 'hello@@world' FROM DUAL
),
bounds (value, start_pos, end_pos) AS (
  SELECT value,
         1,
         INSTR(value, '@', 1)
  FROM   data
UNION ALL
  SELECT value,
         end_pos + 1,
         INSTR(value, '@', end_pos + 1)
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  end_pos > 0
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY value SET order_id
SELECT CASE end_pos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR(value, start_pos)
       ELSE SUBSTR(value, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos)
       END AS item
FROM   bounds;
```

Which outputs:

> | ITEM |
> | --- |
> | hello |
> | *null* |
> | world |

Or, if you want the data in columns (rather than rows):

```sql
WITH data (value) AS (
  SELECT 'hello@@world' FROM DUAL
),
bounds (value, pos1, pos2) AS (
  SELECT value,
         INSTR(value, '@', 1, 1),
         INSTR(value, '@', 1, 2)
  FROM   data
)
SELECT SUBSTR(value, 1, pos1 - 1) AS item1,
       SUBSTR(value, pos1 + 1, pos2 - pos1 - 1) AS item2,
       SUBSTR(value, pos2 + 1) AS item3
FROM   bounds
```

Which outputs:

> | ITEM1 | ITEM2 | ITEM3 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | hello | *null* | world |

---

If you did want to use (slower) regular expressions then:

```sql
WITH data (value) AS (
  SELECT 'hello@@world' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT item
FROM   data d
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL(
         SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( d.value, '(.*?)(@|$)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1) AS item
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL < REGEXP_COUNT( d.value, '(.*?)(@|$)')
       )
```

or, for columns:

```sql
WITH data (value) AS (
  SELECT 'hello@@world' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(.*?)(@|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS item1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(.*?)(@|$)', 1, 2, NULL, 1) AS item2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(.*?)(@|$)', 1, 3, NULL, 1) AS item3
FROM   data
```

*(Which both have the same output as above)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c6ac58f33f996fea1258737c70fa5283)*